# What does this parameter(current) do in this AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, parameters, arguments

function currentWeather(current) {
    $.ajax({
        url: current,
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log("Current Weather: ")
        console.log(response);

Comment: That's the request URL, if you execute `currentWeather (https://www.example.com/)` you should get the response from requested URL

Comment: No idea, ask the author, we only know how it works and what it does, not why it is coded that way